# How can I define mariadb root password using command line or ansible?

Tags: ansible, mariadb

I installed mariadb using ansible and I would like to change the root password which is empty by default.

On the net, there are a lots of pages explaining how to change the root password by logging to mariadb.

How is it possible to change this password from the command line ? In this case, I will use the shell or command module of Ansible ?

Or best, is it possible to define it during installation or using Ansible only ?

Comment: See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html

Comment: See also https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-secure-installation/ or https://github.com/geerlingguy/ansible-role-mysql/blob/master/tasks/secure-installation.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From 10.4 MariaDB is configured with [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security) authentication, there is no "empty" password, it doesn't have one set.

This means you cannot login with a password, it requires `unix_socket` which is running as the same unix user as the database user.

This means that using ansible over root ssh will work without appearing to need a password.

Ansible has a non-default [check_implicit_admin: true](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/mysql/mysql_user_module.html#parameter-check_implicit_admin) that should be used.

While you can [SET PASSWORD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/), it ultimately makes your system less secure because now you have an additional way you can access your system as a non-root unix user (see trade-offs in first link).

Comment: Thanks @danplack The solution with  check_implicit_admin: true runs. I created my users with the requested grants. Thanks again.